# setState updates state and triggers render but I still don't see it in view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I have a simple word/definition app in React. There is an edit box that pops up to change definition when a user clicks on "edit".  The new definition provided is updated in the state when I call `getGlossary()`, I see the new definition in inspector and a console.log statement in my App render() function triggers too. Unfortunately, I still have to refresh the page in order for the new definition to be seen on screen. I would think that calling set state for this.state.glossary in the App would trigger a re-render down to GlossaryList and then to GlossaryItem to update it's definition but I'm not seeing it :(.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      glossary: [],
      searchTerm: '',
    }

    this.getGlossary = this.getGlossary.bind(this); //not really necessary?
    this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    this.handleAddGlossaryItem = this.handleAddGlossaryItem.bind(this);
    this.handleDeleteGlossaryItem = this.handleDeleteGlossaryItem.bind(this);
    //this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition = this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition.bind(this);
  }

  getGlossary = () => {
    console.log('getGlossary fired');
    axios.get('/words').then((response) => {
      const glossary = response.data;
      console.log('1: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.glossary));
      this.setState({ glossary }, () => {
        console.log('2: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.glossary));
      });

    })
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    //console.log('mounted')
    this.getGlossary();
  }

  handleSearchChange = (searchTerm) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm });
  }

  handleAddGlossaryItem = (glossaryItemToAdd) => {
    //console.log(glossaryItemToAdd);
    axios.post('/words', glossaryItemToAdd).then(() => {
      this.getGlossary();
    });
  }

  handleDeleteGlossaryItem = (glossaryItemId) => {
    console.log('id to delete: ' + glossaryItemId);
    axios.delete('/words', {
      data: { glossaryItemId },
    }).then(() => {
      this.getGlossary();
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render app fired');
    const filteredGlossary = this.state.glossary.filter((glossaryItem) => {
      return glossaryItem.word.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase());
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-grid-layout">
          <div className="form-left">
            <SearchBox handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange} />
            <AddWord handleAddGlossaryItem={this.handleAddGlossaryItem} />
          </div>
          <GlossaryList
            glossary={filteredGlossary}
            handleDeleteGlossaryItem={this.handleDeleteGlossaryItem}
            getGlossary={this.getGlossary}
          //handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition={this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

GlossaryItem.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import EditWord from './EditWord.jsx';
const axios = require('axios');

class GlossaryItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isInEditMode: false,
        }
        this.glossaryItem = this.props.glossaryItem;
        this.handleDeleteGlossaryItem = this.props.handleDeleteGlossaryItem;
        this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition = this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition.bind(this);
        this.handleEditClick = this.handleEditClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition = (updateObj) => {
        console.log('update object: ' + JSON.stringify(updateObj));
        axios.put('/words', {
            data: updateObj,
        }).then(() => {
            this.props.getGlossary();
        }).then(() => {
            this.setState({ isInEditMode: !this.state.isInEditMode });
            //window.location.reload();
        });
    }

    handleEditClick = () => {
        // display edit fields
        this.setState({ isInEditMode: !this.state.isInEditMode });
        // pass const name = new type(arguments); data up to App to handle with db
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="glossary-wrapper">
                <div className="glossary-item">
                    <p>{this.glossaryItem.word}</p>
                    <p>{this.glossaryItem.definition}</p>
                    <a onClick={this.handleEditClick}>{!this.state.isInEditMode ? 'edit' : 'cancel'}</a>
                    <a onClick={() => this.handleDeleteGlossaryItem(this.glossaryItem._id)}>delete</a>
                </div>
                {this.state.isInEditMode ?
                    <EditWord
                        id={this.glossaryItem._id}
                        handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition={this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition}
                    /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

EditWord

```
import React from 'react';

class EditWord extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            definition: ''
        };

        this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition = this.props.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition;
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let definition = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ definition });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        //console.log(event.target[0].value);
        let definition = event.target[0].value;
        let update = {
            'id': this.props.id,
            'definition': definition,
        }
        //console.log(update);
        this.handleUpdateGlossaryDefinition(update);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="glossary-item">
                <div></div>
                <input type="text" name="definition" placeholder='New definition' value={this.state.definition} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
export default EditWord;
```

Thank you[image]

Comment: when I change GlossaryItem key to =glossaryItem.definition instead of glossaryItem._id it works as I expect but seems counterintuitive since I want to ensure the ids are unique. The _id value used comes from MongoDB auto id.

Comment: If the key is not changed, then React will not update the list item because it has not changed from React's perspective. It is a part of reconciliation React uses to optimize rendering.

Comment: Thanks @PR7. I read the React article on Reconciliation but I'm still not quite grasping my problem. Most of the stuff I've read thus far recommends using static, unique keys (like from a database) that wouldn't change but I'm definitely experiencing the behavior you mentioned where if the key doesn't change, React doesn't update. Since the code works just fine for DELETE and ADD operations, would it be advised to just do that that process for an update?

Comment: You are missing the `render` method in your `App` component

Comment: Thanks @JoseTomas - Some of the file was missing for some reason. I edited the post to include the render function

Comment: Perfect, can you add the component `GlossaryList`, it looks that he is responsible for not updating filtered items

Comment: @learyjk The `key` must uniquely identify each list item. When we update a word, we break this rule as the `key` is no longer unique because now definition of word has changed. I think in this case the `key` should be composite like `_id + definition`. Also, I think using only definition as `key` can cause similar issue if multiple words have same definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of GlossaryItem I set

```
this.glossaryItem = this.props.glossaryItem;
```

because I am lazy and didn't want to have to write the word 'props' in the component. Turns out this made react loose reference somehow.

If I just remove this line of code and change all references to this.glossaryItem.xxx to this.pros.glossaryItem.xxx then it works as I expect! On another note, the line of code can be moved into the render function (instead of the constructor) and that works too, but have to make sure I'm accessing variables properly in the other functions outside render.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way I can see to fix this is to map the data to make the id uniquely identify each list item (even in case of update). We can to do this in `getGlossary()` by modifying the `_id` to `_id + definition`.

```js
getGlossary = () => {
  console.log('getGlossary fired');
  axios.get('/words').then((response) => {
    // Map glossary to uniquely identify each list item
    const glossary = response.data.map(d => {
      return {
        ...d,
        _id: d._id + d.definition,
      }
    });
 
    console.log('1: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.glossary));
    this.setState({ glossary }, () => {
      console.log('2: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.glossary));
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: This is useful and helped me come up with a good solution